# Cannot find name 'NDEFReader'

Tags: angular, nfc, ndef

I am trying to use NDEFReader for my angular project but I got the Cannot find name 'NDEFReader' error.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG1vM.png)
I am using angular 17 right now and I already install @types/w3c-web-nfc. But I still got `Cannot find name 'NDEFReader'` error. Anyone know the solution?